# Docker nuxt js and django getting error (Econnrefused)

Tags: node.js, django, docker, nuxt.js

i am currently working on docker with django and nuxt js. I can get json data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts in asyncData or nuxtServerInit it's correctly fetching and getting no error. But when i want to fetch from my django rest api service is getting error (cors headers added). I tested to fetching posts from django rest api with created() hook and it's working. I don't understand why its getting error.

pages/index.vue

```
export default {
  asyncData(context){
    return context.app.$axios.$get('http://127.0.0.1:8000') // this is throwing an error
      .then((res) => {
        let posts = [];
        posts = res;
        return { posts: res }
      })
  },
  created() {
    this.$axios.$get('http://127.0.0.1:8000') // this is not throwing any error
      .then(e => {console.log(e);})
  }
}
```

my docker compse ile

```
version: '3'

networks: 
  main:
    driver: bridge

services: 
  api:
    container_name: blog_api
    build: 
      context: ./backend
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes: 
      - ./backend:/app
    networks: 
      - main

  web:
    container_name: blog_web
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes: 
      - ./frontend:/code
    networks: 
      - main
```

backend docker file

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

ADD . /app
```

frontend dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine

WORKDIR /code/

COPY . . 
EXPOSE 8080

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=8080


RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Nuxt-config.js

```js
server: {
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?